# QTreeView disable showing of root node

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

In my project I'm using a `QTreeView` in order to display a plot configuration. On top I have a root node called `PlotConfig` containing several plot windows. Each plot window contains several simple xy plots.

So basically, I have something like this:

[image: My Plot Configuration]

I'm using my own `QAbstractItemModel` in order to display this plot configuration. It all works fine, but the root node `PlotConfig` is really distracting the user.

So I want something like this:

[image: My desired Plot Configuration]

Is there a way to disable the showing of the root node? Either directly in `QTreeView` or in the `QAbstractItemModel`. What I basically want is a `QList` but with each entry behaving like a tree.

Comment: Did you try calling `setRootIndex` ?

Comment: No. But how should it help me? I needto display several PlotWindow nodes beneath my PlotConfig node.

Comment: Hmm, so basically you want to have several root nodes (think I understood it now) ? In that case I'm not sure, but you can try it :)

Comment: Many thanks for the hint anyway. I included some pictures for illustration.

Comment: Thanks for pics! From QT docs `The root can be invalid.` So I would try setting it to invalid. This implies there is no root, which looks a lot like what you need.

Comment: You can use ```setRowHidden```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a workable approach that fits into my existing code.

Comment: Still not working. Seems that `setRowHidden` also hides all children of the hidden node. That is not my intention. My `QTreeView` became blank.

Comment: I assume you tried setRootIsDecorated(false) to reduce the visual impact and it didn't suffice.

Comment: Even calling `setExpanded` to true previous to hiding the node is of no help. :-(

Comment: This was my first try, but `setRootIsDecorated` does something completely different. Just take a look in the docs. :-)

Comment: @Aleph0, Yep, I have also a custom ```QAbstractItemModel``` and with my implementation, I can hide the first top level node without hide the children, can you show your implementation please ?

Comment: Difficult. It is already connected with many other pieces. But what I tried is essentially something like the following. 
`
QModelIndex root;
qtreeview->setExpanded(root, true);
qtreeview->setRowHidden(root.row(), root.parent(), true);
`

Comment: @Aleph0, ```setRowHidden``` is not the behavior that you want.
If you have your own model, what you use to store your data to show ? Can you show your ```rowCount```, ```index``` and ```parent``` method ?

Comment: @ThibautB., Interesting. Can I store the information which index to show inside the QModelIndex? Is it this way round?

Comment: As you have your own model, maybe you could set as root-items all the children of your `PlotConfig` node. That requires some code for the mapping but I can't think of a simpler way right now.

Comment: @Aleph0 for my example, I use my ```treeView``` to show xml data, If I want to show the root, I take the xml root. If I want only children, I ignore the root when I put my data in the model. So it's depend to your implementation.

Comment: @ThibautB., Seems to be a very clever way to do it. It will investigate this solution, but it will take some time. I'm using a somewhat generic TreeModel, that is already included in many parts of my software. Thanks.

Comment: @Aleph0, Good luck ;) If you need more advice, just ask. Regards

Answer (score 4):

setRowHidden also hides the child nodes which (I guess) is not intended. In your example you have got a root node called PlotConfig. I assume it is a child node of the invisibleRootItem. In such a case you need to use setRootIndex:

```
setRootIndex(model.invisibleRootItem()->child(0, 0)->index());
```

This should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same appearance, eventually realized the tree can have multiple 'root' nodes (beneath the implicit invisible root node) i.e. can call addTopLevelItem for Window1, Window2, Window3 etc.

```
QTreeWidgetItem* rootItem;
rootItem = new QTreeWidgetItem (ui->tree->invisibleRootItem());
rootItem->setText(0, "Window1");
ui->tree->addTopLevelItem(rootItem);

rootItem = new QTreeWidgetItem (ui->tree->invisibleRootItem());
rootItem->setText(0, "Window2");
ui->tree->addTopLevelItem(rootItem);
```

Comment: Similar in my case... I realized that I just needed to not build the first level to get the desired result.